# Cannot remotely connect to server while it's connected to WAN port

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, remote-access, local-area-network, wide-area-network

It may appear like a really dumb question but

why can't I remotely connect to my server when it's connected to the WAN port of the router?

It was working when the server was connected through any other LAN port. (I could connect just by opening the Remote Desktop Connection software and putting 'server' as computer name)

EDIT: Oh and before changing ports I did change the properties of a connection to share it over the network (through the router)

Comment: Is this a consumer router?  The "WAN" port is usually not a switched connection, so you'll need to make considerations for routing (making sure it's allowed), addressing (using a different subnet for the WAN link, making sure the server and router both have addresses on that subnet) and potentially NAT.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I don't know what exactly is a consuming router (even though I googled it), it's a TP-LINK 300M Wireless N Router Model No. TL-WR941N / TL-WR941ND. I'll try the subnet thing.

EDIT: When I try to put the wan ip and lan ip on the same subnet it says: WAN IP address and LAN IP address cannot be in a same subnet. Please input another IP address.

Comment: Right - it's a routed interface, so they'd need different subnets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what you are trying to achieve - the WAN port should be connected to your WAN connection i.e. something that connects to the internet.

Everything else should be on your LAN ports, or on switches connected to these.

If you are just testing something out, then you could give your server a static address on a subnet different to your internal one, then set a static ip address on your router in the same subnet as the server, e.g.:

Lets say your router's internal address is 192.168.0.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, this means your local subnet is 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.254 (as well as the reserved addresses 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.255).

You could then set your server with static ip 192.168.1.1 subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and your router's WAN interface to have static ip 192.168.1.2 subnet mask 255.255.255.0, then from your internal network you should be able to access 192.168.1.1 to get to your server.

The only real reason I can think to do so is if you have multiple WAN ip's and you wish to have your server on one of these so it can be accessed externally, but I would strongly advise you to have your server internal and set up relevant port forwarding instead.

Comment: Actually I'm doing this because I have 2 internet connections. I connected the 2 internet connections to a PC (windows server 2003) and the PC to the WAN port of the router. Like that I can easily switch between th 2 connections. To set up these connection I did all the config stuff through Remote Access (when the server was connected though LAN) and it bugged when I activated connection sharing property. Then I switched the server connection port from LAN to WAN to give internet to the router. And now I can actually access the web ser though my browser but can't connect through remote access.

Comment: And I tried changing IPs (new comment due to character restriction)